# Android onStartCommand Service

Tags: java, android, service

I have a service that I am trying to run constantly as long as the user has it on.  The problem is the service uses a ton of memory; I'm guessing because it notifies the users and displays images constantly.  So I put the bulk of my code in another activity.  The service just calls the activity.

### The issue is that I'm trying to use the return Start_Sticky to restart the service when it needs to.  It takes about 2 hours before it uses up enough memory to need to restart.  When it does restart it doesn't do the onStartCommand am I missing something?

```
public class AUTOAlarmService extends Service {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Intent DI = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AUTOSERVICES.class);
    DI.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getApplication().startActivity(DI);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should reconsider some work done because your service is taking too much resources and that shouldnt be happening any way. There are many applications with a lot of services but non have problem of restarting the device for that matter.

However if you want to restart a service you have to stop and then start the service again.

```
stopService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ya I've been combing through the code fixing what I can.  So just having this in my code ensures that when the service restarts the onstartcommand method runs again?

Comment: Yes It does. Because your service is stopped. BTW I was thinking may be this help you a little bit in a better way to write the service. Check the link, https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService

Comment: It is restarting but the memory is still all used up.  My app is using over 50MB and then when I call stopService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class)); its still using the same amount of memory

Comment: Issue was to restart the service. That is reolved. Open up a new question. And send me the link. Provide your activity's code so that I can look into the code and help you out with the issue. I'll be glad to help you. And please dont forget to tick mark this answer as a correct answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Here is the link and thanks for the method Ahmed  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107778/how-to-reset-android-service-memory